# How can I randomize rotation on z-axis with hair particles?

Tags: particles

So I have all these boxes I made, but I wanna randomize it so it doesn't look so repetative. [image]

It doesn't seem to wanna rotate correctly on the z-axis, it just rotates weird on goes through the ground. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, you talk about two different things, randomness and rotating weird and going through the ground... have you tried to enable the *Advanced* option, activate *Rotation* and play with its *Random* value.

Comment: Hi moonboots! I figured this was a common issue and didn't really elaborate. Activating rotation in advanced option is what I have done. No motter what setting I put the boxes wont rotate on the correct axis. Check the image: https://imgur.com/a/hLMt4bz

Comment: check the Initial Orientation setup, if it still doesn't work maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

For random rotation: Enable the *Advanced* option, activate *Rotation*, play with the *Random* value.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks! This is what I have done, and it messes up everything if i set Orientation Axis to anything but none. https://imgur.com/hBDN4YZ

Comment: What is your Initial Orientation setup? Choose Global Z for example

Comment: Thanks! This is what I have tried. I found out however if I rotate the objects I use in the particle system on the x-axis everything looks good. Really weird how it works though. I don't understand why. However, it works